# Track report usage and report export

Tags: reporting, history-tracking

Requirement is to track report usage and report export.

I have went through this link:
http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter15/release-notes/rn_forcecom_security_elf.htm

I executed /services/data/v32.0/sobjects/Report in workbench But I was not able to get running user info.

Is there a way to get user's info who is running the report.

Answer (score 3):

The `EventType` to monitor report is `ReportExport`.

You can try below query,

```
/services/data/v32.0/query?q=SELECT+Id+,+EventType+,+LogDate+,+LogFileLength+,+LogFile+FROM+EventLogFile+WHERE+EventType+=+'ReportExport'
```

Check [Query Event Log Files](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/event_monitoring/event_monitoring_query)

Comment: Is it possible to monitor which user is only running the report.Monitoring ReportExport will give the userId of user who has exported it.Because I tried by replacing EventType+=+'ReportExport' with ventType+=+'Report' and it did not gave any results,even though I have been running reports from last 2-3 days.